# Android: adb logcat -c does not seem to flush the logs

Tags: android, adb, logcat

My understanding is that **adb logcat -c** will completely flush the log buffer.
 Before I start the application, I do **adb logcat -c**.
 After launching the application I do this:

```
 adb logcat -d -s WeatherServiceSync:D
```

But, the logs seem to keep getting appended each time as shown below

```
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onCreate() - service created anew
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onBind() - client has invoked bindService()
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onUnbind() - client has invoked unbindService()
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onDestroy() - service is being shut down
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onCreate() - service created anew
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onBind() - client has invoked bindService()
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onUnbind() - client has invoked unbindService()
D/WeatherServiceSync( 1932): onDestroy() - service is being shut down
```

As you can see, the set of lines from onCreate to onDestroy are getting replicated.

Is there anything I can do to flush the log buffer?

Comment: Is it possible that your code is binding twice? Or that you are hitting the same issue as this bug that has been reported on Android 5.0? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78916

Comment: look at the time stamps of the events to avoid confusion

Comment: @AlexP. I am very sure that the code is not binding twice. The bug report that you have mentioned seems to be what I am facing.